# Edit command not working in Windows command line

Tags: windows, cmd

I am using the below command to open and edit the a file through command prompt. But in my system does not allow that files to edit and return the error. But in my laptop editor window is opened to edit this file.

```
'edit' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: What version of Windows are you running on your desktop & laptop??

Comment: Both having windows 7

Answer (score 6):

I suspect that your desktop is running 64-bit Windows 7, whereas your laptop is running 32-bit Windows 7.

As Wikipedia points out, MS-DOS editor [was/is a 16-bit application](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MS-DOS_Editor), and [wouldn't run on 64-bit versions](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/282423) of windows.

See also: https://superuser.com/questions/237023/what-is-the-edit-command-for-64-bit-windows-7

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How can i enable DOS Editor in windows 7 64 bit

Comment: You can't. It won't run. Check the superuser question I linked for some alternatives, like vim